# Transistor to control 4 L298N motor drivers

Tags: transistors, motor

I'm trying to control 4 L298N motor drivers from 1 pin.
The 4 motors obviously need to run at the same time and speed.

I was worried that splitting the IN1, IN2 and ENA signal among the four would draw too much current from this one pin. That's why I'm looking into using a 2N2222 NPN transistor to control the signals.

Am I correct, is this the way to go?
Below is the circuit I use. (Only for the ENA signal, I'd do the same for the IN1 and IN2 signal.)
Although, when the ENA is LOW, I can hear the motor making very silent sounds.

Thanks in advance!
t.

[image: circuit design]

Comment: Have you read the data sheet for the current into the control pins? BTW, they are pretty crap devices in many applications.

Comment: They draw typical 30 mA according to the datasheet...

Comment: Which controllers are better to use then?

Comment: That would be 30 micro amp.

Comment: 120 milli amp if I'm correct? and max 400 mA, datasheet says max 100 mA

Comment: \$I_{IH}=100~\mu A ~max\$  (but not pin 1)

Comment: Wow. I completely misread the micro for milli... Apologies!

Comment: The L298 is a horrible part, start over with an FET bridge and some sort of multiplexor maybe an I2C I/O expander